# Value of type 'Category' (aka 'OpaquePointer') has no member 'name'

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, opaque-pointers

I'm working with Swift in Xcode and I receive the following error:

```
Value of type 'Category' (aka 'OpaquePointer') has no member 'name'
```

And I've looked everywhere but I can't find a solution.
Does someone know what to do?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Add the definition of `Category` type. And copy-paste the code instead of the screenshot.

Comment: can you please show your `category` model here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Category did not provide name property

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I also had this occur when attempting the exercise in the Angela Yu course where Category is a core data entity. I was using Xcode 11.3.1. After several attempts of setting the Module to Current Product Module and Codegen to Class Definition followed by Ctrl-B's to rebuild, I still received the error. However, restarting Xcode solved the problem and code completion was then able to suggest the name attribute/property.

Comment: I don't understand why but this solution (restarting Xcode) actually solved same problem I have had. Thank you!

Comment: Same here, same exercise. Restarting worked for me as well.

Comment: I honestly do not understand how xCode is that buggy, that you have to keep restarting the app for certain errors to go away ....

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue while been going through Angela Yu course and I had tried all of the available solution which I could find, but only this one has helped to me:
while your project is opened:

1. press Product on the top pane
2. press Clean Build Folder

**do not use hotkey combination** - just press it with your mouse!
only this method help to me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my DataModel file, I changed entity name and the class name from "Category" to different one, such as "TodoListCategory." Then in my CategoryViewController, I changed all the Category objects to "TodoListCategory" and rebuild. It solved my problem.

After that, you might have error "Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code." Now, try to clean your project by using Shift + Command + K & Option + Shift + Command + K

Answer (score 1):

If you are following Angela Yu's course, I found that by selecting `Manual/None` and then `Class Definition` for the Category Entity under Codegen, the classes are auto-generated.

Also run `cmd + b` afterwards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also in Angela's class. I found that by removing the core data models and reinitiating them as *independent* entities with no relationship, setting up the save and load functions, running the app, and *then* going back to link the relationship solved the issue. I think it has to do with saving the entities as NSManagedObject before being able to reference the attributes. I am guessing that without initiating them as an NSManagedObject the default type is Opaque Pointer. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm following the same lesson.
In my case was just an Xcode bug and "Category" was not recognized as a class.
I just close and re-open it and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'categories' variable form 'var' to 'let'.
From,

```
var categories = [Category]()
```

to

```
let categories = [Category]()
```

Just re-build it and this is working.

Answer (score 0):

If `[Category]()` is not recognized as a NSManagedOject, just put the term Category between two single reversed quotation marks inside the brackets.

[link to example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY6s2.png)

Answer (score 0):

While declaring a array of the type Category, do it like :

```
var categories = [[`Category`]]()
```

(if you have the name of the entity as "Category")

note: There is just a single back tick to the left of category.

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

Please make sure you did not choose Opaque Pointer instead of your Class.
See below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx5W4.png)

if you did, replace Category with 'Category'

Answer (score 0):

We need to change the class Module to "Current Product Module" in inspector on the right

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWb31.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check on the right side panel, in File Selector  if the code generation language has been set to Objective-C. If its Swift change it to Objective-C. Thats how I resolved my issue.